# Adding ContextLoaderListener to web.xml in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to *Spring MVC*. I have a web application. I have the following configuration:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do I need to add the following line to the *web.xml* file?

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Does it work with or without? Just need to try `:)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes you need to add `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml`,
only **if** you want to load other Spring context xml files as well while loading the app
and you can specify them as

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 15):

Only if you have two config xml files. One with Services / DAOs and another with Controller.  If you have configured everything in one spring config file you don't need the `ContextLoaderListener`, just the dispatcher servlet is sufficient.

It is recommended to split the config into two and use the `ContextLoaderListener` to create the root application context and the dispatcher servlet to create the web layer application context.

Answer (score 6):

It is optional, you don't really need it just for Spring MVC (`DispatcherServlet` will do). But adding Spring security to your Spring MVC must be done with

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Just one remark, if using `ContextLoaderListener` you will have to add `DelegatingFilterProxy`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>     
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml as well. Sorry for being four years too late. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little advanced, in my application which is an enterprise app, they construct their own listener class and put in the web.xml. On start up, this customized listener will scan the app to gather all info including resources, external connections, server info ip, jars, etc. The info is accessible in a web page.

Comment: Springboot Actuator does the same job as the customization I described above.