# Manually instantiating Spring beans

Tags: spring, servlets, tomcat7, spring-jdbc, spring-4

I'm trying to reuse our Spring-JDBC based DAO classes and code in a project which has a traditional Java (controller) servlet (not Spring's Dispatcher servlet). So as shown below, I tried to launch the application-config.xml manually using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. However, I get the error shown further below.

```
private static final String CONFIG_PATH = "classpath*:application-config.xml";

private signupDao SignupDao;


ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_PATH);

signupDao = context.getBean(SignupDao.class);
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: **No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.dao.SignupDao] is defined**
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)

Earlier, I did not add the following entry to application-config.xml but even after adding it, I still get the same error as above ("No qualifying bean of type is defined").

```
<bean id="signupDao" class="com.abc.dao.SignupDao"></bean>
```

Any ideas?

The controller servlet is not my own, I get it from a third party, I'm only trying to extend their handlers which is where I'm trying to use Spring autowiring, JDBC etc.

EDIT:

The only bean I'm able to load is `context.getBean(MessageSource.class)`, none of my beans can be loaded. `getBeanDefinitionNames` is returning empty array when I tried earlier. Do you think this is a classpath issue?

Comment: Try removing the `*` from your `CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: I get this error if I do that: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `classpath*:` portion from the `CONFIG_PATH` because `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` already looks in the class path for the file (look at it's name);
2. Ensure that your `application-config.xml` file is in the root of your web application's `WEB-INF/classes` directory, otherwise it will not be in the classpath (this assumes that the file is not packaged in another jar).

Comment: Thanks much, this worked, I was using an example from another project for `classpath*:application-config.xml`, did not think that would be the problem. I got past the initial error and now stuck at: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [application-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl`

Comment: Maybe an issue with missing jar for this bean: <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"></bean>

Comment: Hi, do you know if there's a way to avoid calling `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-config.xml")` in each of my handlers and I don't know which handlers gets called the first time. Is there a huge overhead to loading `application-config.xml` at multiple places in your application? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You could use the normal `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` configured in your web.xml and then grab the ApplicationContext containing your Spring beans from the ServletContext in your handlers. See the javadoc for [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html)

Comment: But, I'm not in a traditional Spring MVC environment, I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11014796/1119716) and it was not reading my `application-config.xml`

Answer (score 2):

To narrow down the problem make sure that the ApplicationContext you're creating is successfully created.

This should return all of the beans' names from the given application context.

```
 context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
```

**Update**

If the ApplicationContext does not list any beans from your xml config, that might be an indication that the resource file is not accessible by the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

One way to check is to do something like this:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application-config.xml")
```

This should return a valid not null stream in case the resource is accessible.

**Note** the format of the resource name. It should not include any prefixes like `classpath:` or `classpath*:`

Comment: The only bean I'm able to load is `context.getBean(MessageSource.class)`, none of my beans can be loaded. getBeanDefinitionNames is returning empty array when I tried earlier. Do you think this is a classpath issue?

Comment: That indicates that no beans have been read from classpath resource (most probably the resource cannot be located with the specified name). Check that the resource is available to `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

Comment: If I change `classpath*:application-config.xml` to just `application-config.xml`, I get an error saying unable to locate application-config.xml, so I think it's able to locate application-config.xml correctly...